# yii2-user Class 'yii\web\AccessControl' not found

Tags: registration, user-registration, yii2-user

I'm trying to install and configure yii2-user module to my yii2 basic application. But it is not working:

First added this to composer.json file:

`"dektrium/yii2-user": "*"`

and updated composer. Then just added this code inside $config not inside components section in config/web.php file:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
    ],
],
```

Then added this to layouts/main.php :

```
$navItems=[
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'Status', 'url' => ['/status/index']],
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']]
  ];
  if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    array_push($navItems,['label' => 'Sign In', 'url' => ['/user/login']],['label' => 'Sign Up', 'url' => ['/user/register']]);
  } else {
    array_push($navItems,['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
        'url' => ['/site/logout'],
        'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']]
    );
  }
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $navItems,
]);
```

And I have two more menu buttons: "Sign in" and "Sign up"
Then when I try to enter this url:

> mysite/index.php?r=user%2Fregistration%2Fregister

It comes:

```
Class 'yii\web\AccessControl' not found
in vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/controllers/RegistrationController.php at line 34
```

or when I hit **Sign in** button in my app, it comes **Page not found** file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I include

`yii\filters\AccessControl` class

instead of

`yii\web\AccessControl` class

And it worked for me